# Cant open .Exe in C# that require Java Runtime Environtment

Tags: java, c#, exe

So i make a arduino model and export it,, i want to open it on my C# program so that it can become HMI for drone. Ive tried this :

```
        Process process = Process.Start(@"C:\Users\Happy\Desktop\model\MPUTeapot.exe");
        int id = process.Id;
        Process tempProc = Process.GetProcessById(id);
        this.Visible = false;
        tempProc.WaitForExit();
        this.Visible = true;
```

but it dont work, seems like the exe need java environtment to be able to work.. what should i add to my code so that this model work on C# ? im open it in the original folder and it can be open, heres my program that i want to open in C# https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1F2NP3dEaxYSDBzelRULVZKcVE.. pls i need help...This is 
[when i open the exe in the original folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hZK3.png)

Comment: Do you have JRE installed?

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `java -version`. Post the results here.

Comment: What happens if you just run the exe?  And does the above program generate an error?

Comment: yeah i have JRE,, but when i type version in cmd, the command is not recognize.. When i open the exe in original folder, it work fine, but when i open using C# it just wont open,, i have add screenshot on whats running if it helps, thanks

Comment: THen it's not added to your PATH. Try to reinstall it.

Comment: @van Keulen ok i tried to reinstall it now, but why the program works fine when i open it in the original folder if i dont have JRE ?

Comment: i have reinstall the java but nothing changed.. i realize in the exe folder, there is java folder with many dll and lib, maybe i should include it in the C# but i dont know wich or how to include it,, anyone can help pls ?